# sklearn:TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use FeatureUnion() function to combine different features:dentisty_undictionary,file_length,tdm. And tdm is a kind of vector generated by TfidfVectorizer().the code is here:

```
process_features = Pipeline(
    [
        ('features',FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[('dentisty_undictionary',train_set.dentisty_undictionary),
                                ('file_length',train_set.file_length),
                                ('tdm',train_set.tdm)])),
        ('svc', SVC(kernel='linear')),
    ])
```

and then I got an Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NBayes_Predict_FeatureUnion.py", line 29, in <module>
    ('tdm',train_set.tdm)])),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 622, in __init__
    self._validate_transformers()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 666, in _validate_transformers
    (t, type(t)))
TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform.'[0.8125, 0.7597402597402597, 0.7703513281919452,.......,0.7914338919925512]' (type <type 'list'>) doesn't
```

I am fresh to sklearn.Any suggestion to solving this Error would be welcomed.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FeatureUnion works on class objects from sklearn which implement the `fit()` and `transform()` methods. You are supplying the data (columns) to FeatureUnion which is why the error.

Remove FeatureUnion and Pipeline and just supply the required columns directly to SVC:

```
train_data = train_set[['dentisty_undictionary', 'file_length', 'tdm']]
model = SVC(kernel='linear')
model.fit(train_data, y)
```

See the [examples here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html#examples-using-sklearn-pipeline-featureunion) to know the proper usage of FeatureUnion.