# Problem Python ML ERROR with wine quality Kaggle exercice

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've tried to do the wine_quality exercice on Kaggle:

Here is my code (the beginning):

```
X= data.drop(["quality"], axis=1)
Y= data["quality"]


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test= train_test_split(X,Y, test_size= 0.2)

def encodage(df):
    
    code= {"positive":1,
    "negative":0,
    "detected":1,
    "not_detected":0}

    for col in df.select_dtypes("object").columns:
        df.loc[:,col]= df[col].map(code)

    return df

encodage(X_train)
encodage(X_test)


model_test= DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

def evaluation(model):
    model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
    ypred= model.predict(X_test)
    print(confusion_matrix(Y_test,ypred))
    print(classification_report(Y_test,ypred))


numerical_features= make_column_selector(dtype_include= np.number)
categorical_features= make_column_selector(dtype_include= np.number)
numerical_pipeline= make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(), StandardScaler(), PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False), SelectKBest(f_classif, k=10))
categorical_pipeline= make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"),OneHotEncoder()),SelectKBest(f_classif, k=10)

preprocessor = make_column_transformer((numerical_pipeline, numerical_features),(categorical_pipeline, categorical_features))

RandomForest= make_pipeline(preprocessor, RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0))
AdaBoost= make_pipeline(preprocessor, AdaBoostClassifier(random_state=0))
SVM= make_pipeline(preprocessor, StandardScaler(),SVC(random_state=0))
KNN =make_pipeline(preprocessor, StandardScaler(), KNeighborsClassifier())

dict_of_models= {"RandomForest": RandomForest, "AdaBoost": AdaBoost, "SVM": SVM, "KNN": KNN}

for name, model in dict_of_models.items():
    print(name)
    evaluation(model)
```

Everything was fine, I had a score of 0.66 with model_test(not visible here), but when I arrive at `for name, model in...` , I have this error:

```
TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform, or can be 'drop' or 'passthrough' specifiers. '(Pipeline(steps=[('simpleimputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
                ('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder())]), SelectKBest())' (type <class 'tuple'>) doesn't.
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't **make_pipeline** steps supposed to be list[] not tuple()

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline.html

check out these other questions :

[ColumnTransformer generating a TypeError when trying to fit_transform pipeline in sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829489/columntransformer-generating-a-typeerror-when-trying-to-fit-transform-pipeline-i)

[sklearn:TypeError: All estimators should implement fit and transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49446917/sklearntypeerror-all-estimators-should-implement-fit-and-transform)